# Server.Execute not executing code in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to make use of constants declared in one ASP file in another file. Here's a basic code overview of what I am trying to accomplish:

**FileA.asp**

```
Const tr__first_name = "First Name"
Const tr__last_name  = "Last Name"
Const tr__english    = "English"
```

**FileB.asp**

```
Server.Execute "FileA.asp"
Response.Write Eval("tr__first_name")
```

What should happen is that when I run *FileB.asp* it should print out "First Name" for the `Response.Write` statement.  If I declare `const tr__first_name` in *FileB.asp* resulting in the following code...

```
Server.Execute "FileA.asp"
Const tr__first_name = "First Name"
Response.Write Eval("tr__first_name")
```

Then *FileB.asp* will print out "First Name" as expected. Any thoughts as to why my first approach won't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Server.Execute only runs FileA.asp as a standalone page within FileB.asp.  In other words, it's not like a programming language making a function call--it is simply running the separate page outside the context of the first page, but displaying the results of the separate page inside the first page.

Do this instead:

```
<!-- #include file="FileA.asp" -->
```

Comment: Right!  See I knew that but for some reason that answer wasn't coming to mind.  Thanks.